# Color in multicolums, in memoir

Tags: memoir, rowcolor

I have this code:

```
\begin{table}[H]

\label{tab:brud}

\centering

\caption{Tabel over dominerende laster ved brudgrænsetilstanden.}

\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}

{XX>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XXX}

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}  &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Dominerende egenlast}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Dominerende vindlast}}  \\

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
& Træ-konstruktion & Beton-konstruktion  & Træ-konstruktion & Beton-konstruktion
\\ 

\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} Regningmæssige last $E_d$ [$\frac{kN}{\mathrm{m^2}}$] &0,660 & 6,600& 0,817 & 5,767
\\

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Dominerende snelast}}    \\

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
& Træ-konstruktion & Beton-konstruktion \\ 

\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} Regningmæssige last $E_d$ [$\frac{kN}{\mathrm{m^2}}$] &\textbf{1,686} & \textbf{6,636} 

\label{fig:brud}

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
```

The document is memoir, and i should have the necessary package.
The problem is that it doesn't color the multicolums, i have tried using \cellcolor but i cant seem to get it working

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: if your colortbl is older than a couple of years or so, rowcolor won't go bast the \multicolumn and you need to use \columncolor agai in the multicolumn, or update.

Comment: And please don't use `'H` floats. This is usually a sign that one has not understood floats.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit later and making your code compilable and running it with TexLive2015, I suposse your `colortbl` was older

```
\documentclass{memoir}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % <-- added
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % <-- added
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}      % <-- changed
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}  % <-- added
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{#1}}}  % <-- added

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Tabel over dominerende laster ved brudgrænsetilstanden.}
\label{tab:brud}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{0.21\textwidth}*{4}{L}}% <--- changed
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}  &
\mc{Dominerende egenlast} & \mc{Dominerende vindlast}  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & Træ-konstruktion & Beton-konstruktion  & Træ-konstruktion & Beton-konstruktion
\\ 
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} Regningmæssige last $E_d$ [$\frac{kN}{\mathrm{m^2}}$] &0,660 & 6,600& 0,817 & 5,767
\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}  
& \mc{Dominerende snelast}                   & &   
\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
& Træ-konstruktion & Beton-konstruktion      & & 
\\ 
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} Regningmæssige last $E_d$ [$\frac{kN}{\mathrm{m^2}}$] &\textbf{1,686} & \textbf{6,636} & & 
\label{fig:brud}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:** I take liberty and add to table (to my opinion) missing part of OP table. Also I add two shortcuts for simpler tyble setting and picture of obtained table.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in the comments, you're probably have an old package there, it's highly recommended to update your TeX. I'v adpated the awnser from Very23 without adding so much stuff:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{booktabs} %Because it's beautiful :) just personal preference
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5} %Changes the rows height globally
\definecolor{LightCyan}{RGB}{192,192,192} %So that you don't have to repeat whole color code again
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Tabel over dominerende laster ved brudgrænsetilstanden.}
\label{tab:brud}
\begin{tabular*}{1\linewidth}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}lllll<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}
%\toprule
\rowcolor{LightCyan} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}\textbf{Dominerende egenlast}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}\textbf{Dominerende vindlast}} \\ %\midrule
\rowcolor{LightCyan} 
 & Træ-konstruktion & Beton-konstruktion & Træ-konstruktion & Beton-konstruktion \\
Regningmæssige last $E_d$ [$\frac{kN}{\mathrm{m^2}}$] &0,660 & 6,600& 0,817 & 5,767 \\
\rowcolor{LightCyan} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}\textbf{Dominerende egenlast}} & & \\
\rowcolor{LightCyan} & Træ-konstruktion & Beton-konstruktion & & \\
Regningmæssige last $E_d$ [$\frac{kN}{\mathrm{m^2}}$] &\textbf{1,686} & \textbf{6,636} & & \\ %\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table with colors on multirow]